# Is there something equivalent to an "initial width" in css

Tags: css, responsive-design, width

I would like to set the width on a `div` so that when it initially displays, it would be set to some fixed value, which I would call the "initial width". If the user resizes their browser to make the width smaller, I would like the `div`'s width to grow smaller but only to a minimum width (which can be set with `min-width`). I can't use the `width` rule to set the initial width because that keeps it fixed at that width even when the browser width gets smaller.

Comment: You can use a percentage based values, or use a the calc function

Comment: using `%` of width solves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use `max-width` and it won't expand beyond a certain width:

```
element {
  max-width: 450px; /* 'initial width' */
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px; /* 'minimum width' */
}
```

Example:

```css
.resizeable {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.element {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizeable"> Resize me!
  <div class="element">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually did this but it didn't work. The only difference between yours and mine was that my content div was a flex with column and its width set to 100%. Also, my resize div was also a flex with column. Only after removing the width on the flex of the content div did it work. Thanks!